# Spring Native fails to start native app after add language:js - Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping'

Tags: java, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, spring-native, graaljs

i've configured a spring native app which should use graalvm js interpreter to run js code.
The app works fine if i build/run it with nashorn interpreter (no native, standard build).
If i build it using native profile and GraalVM js interpreter it fails at runtime (build completed with success and some warnings).

If i remove tomcat dependency (native build, graalvm interpreter, no tomcat) it works fine. My question is: is there a way to run graalvm native image (graalvm js interpreter) and tomcat in the same app? What should i modify?

Graalvm version:22.0.0.2

POM (maven project):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestSpringNativeExe</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <graalvm.version>21.2.0</graalvm.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-release</id>
            <name>Spring release</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-release</id>
            <name>Spring release</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- ... -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-native</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.experimental</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-programmatic</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logback -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
            <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- others -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
            <artifactId>js</artifactId>
            <version>${graalvm.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
            <artifactId>js-scriptengine</artifactId>
            <version>${graalvm.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.graalvm.truffle</groupId>
            <artifactId>truffle-api</artifactId>
            <version>${graalvm.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- ... -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.11.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <removeXmlSupport>false</removeXmlSupport>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- Required with Maven Surefire 2.x -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.9.10</version>
                        <extensions>true</extensions>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>build-native</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>test-native</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>test</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- ... -->
                            <buildArgs>--language:js</buildArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <!-- Avoid a clash between Spring Boot repackaging and native-maven-plugin -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>exec</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Warnings at build time (native build):

```
[1/7] Initializing...                                                                                    (6,7s @ 0,25GB)
Warning: Could not register org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.HikariDriverConfigurationFailureAnalyzer: allDeclaredConstructors for reflection. Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/CannotGetJdbcConnectionExcept
ion.
Warning: Could not register org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.ValidationExceptionFailureAnalyzer: allDeclaredConstructors for reflection. Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ValidationException.
Warning: Could not register org.springframework.boot.liquibase.LiquibaseChangelogMissingFailureAnalyzer: allDeclaredConstructors for reflection. Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: liquibase/exception/ChangeLogParseException.
 Version info: 'GraalVM 22.0.0.1 Java 11 EE'
The bundle named: org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.res.LocalStrings, has not been found. If the bundle is part of a module, verify the bundle name is a fully qualified class name. Otherwise verify the bundle path is accessible in the classpath.
[2/7] Performing analysis...  [*********]                                                               (93,1s @ 3,89GB)
Warning: Could not register complete reflection metadata for org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator. Reason(s): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/util/PartialOrder$PartialComparable
Warning: Could not register complete reflection metadata for org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter$ViolationFieldError. Reason(s): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/Validator, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundE
rror: javax/validation/ConstraintViolation
Warning: Could not register complete reflection metadata for org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator. Reason(s): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/util/PartialOrder$PartialComparable
Warning: Could not register complete reflection metadata for org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.ValidationExceptionFailureAnalyzer. Reason(s): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ValidationException
Warning: Could not register complete reflection metadata for org.springframework.boot.liquibase.LiquibaseChangelogMissingFailureAnalyzer. Reason(s): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: liquibase/exception/ChangeLogParseException
Warning: Could not register complete reflection metadata for org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.HikariDriverConfigurationFailureAnalyzer. Reason(s): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/CannotGetJdbcConnectionException
```

Error at runtime (native image run):

```
13:29:27.327 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping': Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)
        at com.example.SpringNativeApp.main(SpringNativeApp.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
        at java.lang.Class.ensureInitialized(DynamicHub.java:510)
        at java.lang.Class.ensureInitialized(DynamicHub.java:510)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.createRequestMappingHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:351)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.createRequestMappingHandlerMapping(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:543)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:311)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.requestMappingHandlerMapping(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:445)
        at org.springframework.aot.ContextBootstrapInitializer.lambda$initialize$23(ContextBootstrapInitializer.java:168)
        at org.springframework.aot.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionRegistrar$ThrowableFunction.apply(BeanDefinitionRegistrar.java:294)
        at org.springframework.aot.beans.factory.InjectedElementResolver.create(InjectedElementResolver.java:67)
        at org.springframework.aot.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionRegistrar$BeanInstanceContext.create(BeanDefinitionRegistrar.java:211)
        at org.springframework.aot.ContextBootstrapInitializer.lambda$initialize$24(ContextBootstrapInitializer.java:168)
        at org.springframework.aot.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionRegistrar$ThrowableFunction.apply(BeanDefinitionRegistrar.java:294)
        at org.springframework.aot.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionRegistrar.lambda$instanceSupplier$0(BeanDefinitionRegistrar.java:115)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.obtainFromSupplier(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1249)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1191)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected method not found: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$EmptyHandler.handle()
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getMethod(ClassUtils.java:1141)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.<clinit>(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:84)
        ... 31 common frames omitted
```

Comment: As reported in:
https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-native/issues/1510
It's a bug in GraalVm side